# Monitoring reads (per user) in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have thought about monitoring reads for users in Firebase.
Let's say that a user makes a lot of "reads", then I will monitor these "reads" by writing to a counter in a separate document. Once the user has reached 10<sup>4</sup> reads I will tell the user that they have reached their daily quota. In such a case I also want to disable them from making any further reads (for a day), is this possible in Firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not currently possible. At least not in any secure way that would prevent the user from manipulating the value.

Your best solution at present would be to use Firestore or RTDB as a non-public database and then create an API behind the API Gateway to handle your rate limiting.  Then reads go through your API giving you much more control but of course involves losing realtime updates.

Comment: Hi @Brian , do you know if this is still something that firebase is lacking?

Comment: @AugustJelemson AFAIK nothing has changed.  The only solution I can think of, other than the above, would be to give each user their own database and then use Cloud Metrics to trigger an alert when a database's data egress exceeds some limit you set.  Then you could deauthenticate the user.